# Single function to remove all kinds of whitespaces

Tags: php, html, php4

I need a php function to remove all the whitespaces in a string.

I tried str_replace(" ","",$str);

Then I tried rtrim();

But even then I can't remove the spaces that are formed by the

I tried str_replace(" ","",$str);, but its not working.

Then I googled somehow and found out

```
$converted = strtr($str, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_QUOTES)));
    $converted = trim($converted);
    $str = trim($converted, "\xA0");
```

But that is also not working in some cases. Can somebody provide a simple function for removing all the whitespaces.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can doing this using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str); // \s matches any whitespace character
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$string = trim( preg_replace( '/\s+/si', '', $string ), '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Capital `S` matches everything *but* whitespace, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace('/\s+/','',$str)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php